# How can I Listen for Keyboard input without Text Field Java

Tags: java, keyboard, rfid

I am working on a Java application and interfacing with an RFID reader that acts as a keyboard input device.

The application will be used for employee time tracking, so the employee should not see the code that his/her RFID tag contains.

Currently, the application opens a jFrame that asks the employee to scan their tag. This is where I would like to listen for the keyboard input.

All of the RFID tags are 10 digits, so I would like to use some kind of regex to detect when a card is scanned if possible.

If someone could point me in the right direction, or contribute some code I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to read the input of the scanner by adding the following to the constructor of my JFrame.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ System.out.print(e.getKeyChar());}
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
});
```

So it is now confirmed that the Reader is just standard Keyboard input.

Here is an example of what I get for a tag: 0006459027

Now, the big question is, how do I take the characters that I got, and detect that it is a 10 digit string, and from there trigger an event to open a new frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd see if the RFID reader is triggering an `ActionEvent` to be fired when the tag is scanned.  This would be the simplest approach.

Failing that, you would need to attach a `DocumentListener` to the fields underlying document and monitor for changes.

You'll need to decide how best to interrupt the results (as you're likely to get each letter of the RFID at a time).  You could monitor the length of the document or have a `javax.swing.Timer` which triggers after a short delay (you'd reset the timer on each update event triggered by the `DocumentListener`)

Check out

- [JTextField.addActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29)
- [JTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#addDocumentListener%28javax.swing.event.DocumentListener%29)

I'd suggest taking a look at `DocumentFilter` as well, but your interested in the final result, not modifying it.

**UPDATED with DocumentListener Example**

```
// In the classes variable decleration section...
private JTextField rfidField;

// In the classes constructor or UI init method...
rfidField = new JTextField(12);
rfidField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    public void handleUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        if (e.getDocument().getLength() == 10) {

            System.out.println("Trigger me happy...");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    rfidField.setText(null);
                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        handleUpdate(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        handleUpdate(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        handleUpdate(e);
    }
});

// Now don't forget to add the field to your forms container ;)
//////
```

One of things I would be do when you "trigger" the code event is, once you've read it from the text field, is clear the text field (`JTextField.setText(null)`) - IMHO

Comment: Great! Thanks! just added in the add(field), which actually worked without showing the field.

Comment: @MikeGeorge The adding of the field can occur at any time, it's irrelevant to the answer (although still a good idea to mention ;))

Comment: Just one more question, How do I go about resetting the DoucumentListener so I can scan another tag if needed?

Comment: @MikeGeorge That was the last paragraph of my post.  Once you've read the RFID from the text field, set it's text to null or an empty `String` - `JTextField.setText(null)`, that will reset the document to an empty document

Comment: If I do that inside the handleUpdate method I get: "non-static method setText(String) cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @MikeGeorge I've updated my example. First, don't EVERY change the documents contents via its associated field while your inside a document's event, this will crash on you. You need to use the field's reference to change the text. See example

Comment: Thanks! it worked, as you can tell I've never had to do this before.

Answer (score 1):

If the RFID reader acts as a *keyboard* input device, try with [key events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

// frame setup

frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
    {

        System.out.println(ke);

    }

});
```

Otherwise you have to check which kind of event it fires.

Comment: Any tips for implementing this after using NetBeans to generate the "form" which extends javax.swing.JFrame?

Comment: I have no NetBeans knowledge :/ But anywhere you can reference to the frame, you may add a `keyListener` the way I suggested above, just time some keys and you will see the event representation in the console.

Comment: @moonwave99 I'd be VERY careful about using a `KeyListener` while not exactly wrong, it's to easy to circumvent

Comment: @MadProgrammer I do agree, I was more concerned with making-this-plastic-stuff work. There should be a way to intercept just the device's events.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation but with a bar-code scanner.

I really worked hard on a custom `DocumentListener` that would take care of all scenarios, and none of it worked.

Out of desperation, I added an `ActionListener` and it then worked very well.

Here is a code snap-shot :

```
try {
    txtStockItemRef.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println(txtStockItemRef.getText()); 
            DatabaseManager.peformStockItemLookupByBarcodeRef(txtStockItemRef.getText());
        } 
    }); 
} catch(Exception exc) {
    LiveCityRetailTools.handleExceptionWithUserMessage(exc);
}
```